# How to print bigquery parameterized query executed through the Python API?

Tags: google-bigquery

When executing a parameterized query, is it possible to print the SQL that was actually executed (after replacement of the parameters)?

```
from google.cloud import bigquery


client = bigquery.Client()
query_job = client.query(
    "SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE my_table.a > @my_param",
    job_config=bigquery.QueryJobConfig(
        query_params=[
            bigquery.ScalarQueryParam("my_param", "INT64", 8)
        ]
    )
)

print(query_job.final_query)  # Note that query_job.query will print the pre-replacement version
```

The output should be `SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE my_table.a > 8`.

Comment: Could you verify that your query actually executes?  What version of the API are you using?  `query_params` is not a valid keyword argument for `Client.query()` in [the latest version](https://googleapis.dev/python/bigquery/latest/generated/google.cloud.bigquery.client.Client.html#google.cloud.bigquery.client.Client.query) but instead gets wrapped up in the `job_config` argument.

Comment: Sorry, thanks for pointing that out. I just missed the `job_config` arg. It's fixed now.

Comment: I was trying to check my query by using positional or named parameters but couldn't find a way to check it. Any updated on this?